# Android Studio: How to restore default console tabs (restore default layout doesn't work)

Tags: android, android-studio

My Android Studio bottom layout looks like this:
[image]

But I want my Android Studio layout to look like this (missing the Messages, Terminal, Todo, Monitor, logcat tabs, etc.):
[image]

`Window > Restore Default` Layout does not work since I accidentally restored the current layout that I have as the default layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the rectangle at the bottom left corner. That’s the toggle button for the breadcrumbs.

[image]
[image]